# Remove Empty lines using Regular Expression

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

I'm new to iOS develoment, I have the data like this below and i want to remove all the empty lines, Please let me know what the pattern to be applied:

I have used the pattern as @"(\r\n)" and replaced it with @"", but it does not work. Please help me to sort out this issue

```
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-name="seedocs" tvg-logo="RT",RT





http://rt.ashttp14.visionip.tv/live/rt-global-live-HD/playlist.m3u8

#EXTINF:-1 tvg-name="hsn" tvg-logo="hsn",HSN TV

rtsp://hsn.mpl.miisolutions.net:1935/hsn-live01/_definst_/mp4:420p500kB31

#EXTINF:-1 tvg-name="us" tvg-logo="us",USTwit

http://bglive-a.bitgravity.com/twit/live/high

#EXTINF:-1 tvg-name="ALJAZEERA" tvg-logo="aljazeera",Aljazeera

rtmp://aljazeeraflashlivefs.fplive.net/aljazeeraflashlive-live/aljazeera_eng_high

#EXTINF:-1 tvg-name="bbc" tvg-logo="bbc",BBC World News



#EXTINF:-1 tvg-name="vevo" tvg-logo="vevo",Vevo

http://vevoplaylist-live.hls.adaptive.level3.net/vevo/ch1/06/prog_index.m3u8

#EXTINF:-1 tvg-name="vevo2" tvg-logo="vevo2",Vevo 2

http://vevoplaylist-live.hls.adaptive.level3.net/vevo/ch3/06/prog_index.m3u8

#EXTINF:-1 tvg-name="1HD" tvg-logo="1HD",1HD

rtmp://109.239.142.62/live/livestream3
```

Comment: We will help you with *your* code, add it to the question. A few hints, why @"(\r\n)"? Do you really want to replace all line separators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search: `(?:\r?\n){2,}`
Replace: `\r\n`

`\r?\n` is both Windows and Linux compatible. `{2,}` means "two or more instances"

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/bA8jJ4/2)

---

If supported, you can use `\R` instead of `\r?\n` to include other types of Unicode newlines. This may be useful in the future, if not at present.

Answer (score 4):

```
[\r\n]+
```

You can use this instead.See demo.Replace by `\n`.

https://regex101.com/r/vV1wW6/26

```
NSString *string = @"Your multiline string";
NSError *error = nil;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"[\r\n]+" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
NSString *modifiedString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length]) withTemplate:@"\n"];
```

Comment: I doubt that is the result the OP wants, he want's to remove the blank lines, probably not all line breaks.

Comment: `[\r\n]+` could potentially match a series of CR like `\r\r\r\r\r`, so I suggest changing it to a non-capturing matching group: `(?:\r\n)+`

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use the `NSString` method
`stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:`
with the option:
`NSRegularExpressionSearch`.

There is no need to use `NSRegularExpression`.

```
NSString *cleanText = [originalText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[\r\n]+" withString:@"\n" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, text.length)];
```

This will replace all runs of any combinations of `\r` and/or `\n` with a single `\n` thus elimination all bank lines.